# How to add categories to top navigation bar?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, uinavigationbar, admin, static-block

[Please Click Here To My Website](http://www.trenpon.com)
In Magento Admin Panel, I try to create a new category on the top navigation bar, but when ever I add a new block is not displaying on the top. If you see:(They are actually are all in one static block)

- Best Sales
- New Products
- Contact Us
- About Us
- Testing

---

What I am trying to do is adding a new category to the top NAV, and have different left NAV category in each of the top NAV category.

- Can some one tell me why when I add a new static block is not showing on the top?
- And how to add different left Nav bar in each of the top Nav Vategory?

Answer (score 0):

This is the free module to install which can help to manage top manage top navigation bar [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/navigation-bar-administrator.html)

Comment: shet really? you use this too?